# Spring boot webclient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am using webClient in spring boot for making api Calls.

My code:

```
  webClient
            .post()
            .uri("/connect")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization",boltTerminalApiKey)
            .body(Mono.just(boltTerminalAPIRequest),BoltTerminalAPIRequest.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
          .block();
```

Facing this issue

[image]

How can we fix this?

Comment: 401 meabs that your authorization is not good or rejected. Check your authorization header.

Comment: Side note: even when you reach this call with a 201 after authorizing, I think Reactor may prevent you from doing a blocking operation. And if not, it still defeats the purpose of writing a reactive application - you should just return the Mono here.

Comment: Header shall be set as `.header("Authorization","Bearer "+boltTerminalApiKey)`